# Python not converting str to int

Tags: python

i made this code to convert dates:

```
while True: 
    d = input("Date: ")
    if "/" in d:
        try:
            x, y, z = d.split("/")
            float(x)
            int(y)
            int(z)
            print(type(x))
            print(type(y))
            print(type(z))
        # print(f" {z : 03d} ")
        # print(f" {x : 03d} ")
        # print(f" {y : 03d} ")
            break
        except:
            break
    if "," in d:
        x, y = d.split(",")
        print(x,y)
```

but when i give an input of:

`Date: 9/8/2020`

it is not converting the strings to ints, output is:
`<class 'str'>`
`<class 'str'>`
`<class 'str'>`

WHY??

expecting the class type to be int

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
float(x)
int(y)
int(z)
```

to:

```
x = float(x)
y = int(y)
z = int(z)
```

Without the assignments, all it's doing is evaluating the expressions, then discarding the results.

Comment: Thank you for helping a beginner!! I was going round on circles for a while

Answer (score 0):

```
while True: 
    d = input("Date: ")
    if "/" in d:
        try:
            x, y, z = d.split("/")
            x = float(x)
            y = int(y)
            z = int(z)
            print(type(x))
            print(type(y))
            print(type(z))
        # print(f" {z : 03d} ")
        # print(f" {x : 03d} ")
        # print(f" {y : 03d} ")
            break
        except:
            break
    if "," in d:
        x, y = d.split(",")
        print(x,y)
```

you are just converting not assigning it in to the variable